# You're at a restaurant waiting for a table. People leave a table, now can you say "a table just became free"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english, conversation, indian-english

You're at a restaurant waiting for a table. People leave a table, now can you say "a table just became free"? or "a table just became available"? or something else? What's the most common/natural way of expressing this?

Comment: Interesting how both customers and servers can be "waiting" for a table. I believe you are speaking from the server's perspective, yes?

Comment: Your table is ready.

Comment: @Christopher - A table can become _free_ before it is _ready_. To the O.P.: I wonder if you wanted to ask this on [ell.se]; it seems like a better fit for that site.

Comment: I'd say "a table just *opened up*", but that doesn't mean it's available; it probably needs to be bussed (have dirty dishes and glasses removed) and wiped clean before it's ready for new customers.

Comment: @carrizal: servers wait *on* a table and customers usually wait *for* a table, although some native speakers of English, when they're waiting to be seated, do indeed say "We are waiting *on* a table".  I had some friends from Long Island, NY who used "waiting on", like German "warten auf".

Comment: A non-native speaker here. I think I'd use *A table is available* (or perhaps *There's a table available*) with cordial words such as *sir, Ms., now* etc.) if I want to make it clear that a table is just "available" but not "ready" yet. Otherwise, I'd use *Your table is ready* as @Christopher suggested.

Comment: **Who** do you want to say it to?

Answer (score 2):

There would be multiple ways depending on tense, but in general conversation your second example would be the most common/natural way most people would express themselves: "The table just became available."

Answer (score 2):

A table has just become available...